# `focused(_:equals)` not working but deprecated method is (`focusable(_:onFocusChanged:)`)

Tags: swiftui

Here is the focus code that works for me:

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    @State var text: String = "testing"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
            Text("top")
                .padding()
                .focusable(true, onFocusChange: { focused in
                    text = "top focus"
                })
            Text("bottom")
                .padding()
                .focusable(true, onFocusChange: { focused in
                    text = "bottom focus"
                })
        }
        
    }
}
```

However, I get a deprecation warning for  the `.focusable(_:onFocusChange:)` lines. So naturally I go to replace it with the non-deprecated solution. I come to find out that that's using `@FocusState` and `focused(_:equals)`. So I implement this:

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    @FocusState var focus: Focus?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(focus?.rawValue ?? "no focus")
            Text("top")
                .padding()
                .focused($focus, equals: .top)
            Text("bottom")
                .padding()
                .focused($focus, equals: .bottom)
        }
        
    }
}

enum Focus: String {
    case top = "top focus", bottom = "bottom focus"
}
```

But it doesn't work at all. No views are getting focus. Keep in mind this is on macOS and I'm running 13.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure each `Text` views are also focusable by using the `.focusable()` modifier. While some views, such as `TextField`, are focusable by default; `Text` is not:

```swift
VStack {
    Text("top")
        .focusable()
        .focused($focus, equals: .top)
    Text("bottom")
        .focusable()
        .focused($focus, equals: .bottom)
}
```